# German language websites for Ubuntu

Tags: community

At Ask Ubuntu everything is in English. Are there any German language websites for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides https://ubuntuusers.de/, which Takkat mentioned, there are German translations of the official documentation:

- [Ubuntu Desktop Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/)
- [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/)

The pages will be displayed in the preferred language specified by your browser, so to make Firefox show the docs in German, select *Edit -> Preferences -> Content -> Languages* and make German be the first language in that list.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu comes with many different languages including all variants of German. This also includes manuals and helpfiles for most applications included. Different to this providing different locales to the main [Ubuntu website](https://www.ubuntu.com/) would make it very hard to maintain.

Still there is an "official" German Ubuntu forum where you can get help on all topics:

- [Ubuntuusers](https://ubuntuusers.de/)

People there also maintain a tremendously helpful Wiki for many topics and 
applications. Asking questions or participating in discussions requires registration which is free of charge.

Comment: +1 for ubuntuusers.de; Is pretty much the best German language site.